# Breakpoints ignored in package unit test

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Breakpoints set in the testable code are ignored during unit tests. In the test schemes, debug executable is checked.

What might I try to use breakpoints?

Package:

- Swift 5.3 Swift Package Manager
- Perhaps irrelevant, but a symlink is used to share code between two libraries: one with logic and the other extending XCTest with custom assertions for that logic. This was the cleanest-for-client workaround to the problems Xcode has in importing packages that extend XCTest.

Comment: I am having the same problem in my project. Did you find a solution?